# Divide each element of numpy matrix by the unit vector of that row

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

How to divide each row element of numpy array by the unit vector of that row?

For eg :

```
A = np.array([[ 0. , 1.],[ 2.,  4.],[ 1.,  5.]])
```

So, needed output matrix should be :

```
[[ 0.0 , 1.][0.0,   0.0][0.19611614 , 0.98058068]]
```

I obtained this by using following snippet:

```
for row in A:
    t=np.sqrt(np.sum(row**2))
    row = row/t
```

But when I use this code on my very big matrix it throws below error :
"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide" .But I don't have any invalid value in my numpy "A" array. I checked using "argwhere" check. It returns an empty list always.This A matrix is either having 0 or some values.I know there should be some easier to perform this calculation.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
from __future__ import division

dists = np.linalg.norm(A,axis=1,keepdims=1)
out = np.where(np.isclose(dists,0), 0, A/dists)
```

Basically, with `np.where` we are choosing between two options, the syntax being :

```
np.where(condition, option1, option2)
```

To avoid any warnings and write back the result to input, use a mask -

```
mask = ~np.isclose(dists,0).ravel()
A[mask] /= dists[mask]
```

**Explanation :** For each array element in the boolean array `condition`, it would choose between the corresponding elements in the two arrays `option1` or `option2`. In our case, if the `dists` element is close to zero being detected with `np.isclose`, which signifies that all elements in that row are all zeros corresponding  to that `dists` value. Thus essentially, if `condition` is `zero`, we are assigning `0` as the output, otherwise choosing the computed `dist` values for the output.

---

Few alternatives to get `dists` with `np.sum` and `np.einsum` for performance -

```
np.sqrt(np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A,A))[:,None]
np.sqrt((A**2).sum(1))[:,None]
```

`einsum` basically computes squaring and `sum-reduction` along the second axis with `np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A,A)`. Rest of it is just `square-root` and adding a new axis with `[:,None]` for alignment and later divisions against `A`.

The later method of `sum` is basically `squaring` and `summing` with `np.sum` along the second axis. Rest of it is same as with `einsum`.

Comment: Can you tell me why it is giving me that warning?

Comment: @NikitaGupta Probably because you are dividing by `0`. What's the datatype of the input array?

Comment: @NikitaGupta I think its because you have a zero valued element and the `norm` value is `0` as well. So, for that `0/0` division, its probably throwing that warning.

Comment: A = csc_matrix((100,28102),dtype = np.longdouble).toarray()

Comment: Later on I'm filling some indexes in A with some values.

Comment: @NikitaGupta So, even with `np.true_divide` on such all zero rows, all elements would become all `NaNs`. Is that what you expect as the output?

Comment: No, it should not become NAN. It should be zeros only.

Comment: I mean whenever there is a case like 0/0 answer should be 0 only not nan

Comment: what is this line doing ? "out[(A==0).all(1)] = 0"

Comment: @NikitaGupta Sorry, just added a better way.

Comment: please explain "out = np.where(np.isclose(dists,0), 0, A/dists)" . and few alternatices approach

Comment: dists = np.linalg.norm(A,axis=1,keepdims=1)
out = np.where(np.isclose(dists,0), 0, A/dists) ; it is still giving the same warning

Comment: @NikitaGupta If you are not too picky about warnings, you can ignore that. The final value would be okay. Added explanation on `np.where` part.

Comment: Another approach to avoid warning :1.) Get all the normalized values in dists lists. 2.) Get index of all non-zero elements from dists list. 3.) Divide only those matrix rows by dist value whose indexes are obtained in step 2. Can you suggest cleaner way to implement step 2 and 3?